# Conversion of varchar to number

Tags: sql, oracle, select, insert

I have a question that bothers me. How can i convert a varchar to number when inside the varchar value consists of alphabets.

For my varchar price column values:

```
14dollars10cents
15dollars20cents
```

By converting it to varchar to number price column, the values should be:

```
1410
1520
```

I know that if the varchar does not consists any alphabets, it can auto convert by"

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, PRICE) FROM Table
```

Is there any way to get rid of the alphabets in the middle as I would like to do mathematical function on it.

Updated attempt of putting fixed point number in:

```
SELECT CAST (Replace(REPLACE(PRICE, 'dollars', '.'),'cents','') AS Number(4,2))) 
FROM TEST;
```

Thanks

Comment: Are the positions fixed? Then substring operations would work. Otherwise, a regular expression to remove all non-digits.

Comment: well check once in http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/curr2words.htm

Comment: Hi the positions aren't fixed. the solution that dinup provided will not work as the formatfixedpoint only available to certain strings.

Comment: Use REGEXP_REPLACE and you can do everything you need in one SQL statement. I'll leave an answer showing how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(YourVarcharCol, 'dollars', '') AS INT) FROM Table
```

The issue with this is it will break if the varchar still contains alpha-numeric characters.

Comment: Ok i have tested out from your given solution. It gives me an error of invalid number. When i select cast(replace(price, 'dollars', 'cents') as number from test

Comment: I have updated my current solution that i have done. Is it possible to case 3 values ? because my table data consist of null values

Comment: ... your trying you change 'dollars' with 'cents' first off you need to change 'dollars' with ''

try SELECT CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(YourVarcharCol, 'dollars', ''), 'cents', '') AS INT) FROM Table

Comment: Understood. Just another question. What if i want to change it into fixed point number Number(4,2). Is it possible after replacing ?

Comment: well you could try it with any type that you want... i have not actually tested any of this so i'm not sure :)

Comment: well thank you very much. I tried it out by adding one '.' in front. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You could just use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to remove all non digit characters:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(price, '[^[:digit:]]')
  FROM table;
```

To then convert this to a number:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_REPLACE(price, '[^[:digit:]]'))
  FROM table;
```

If you want to add the point in then you can do that with `REGEXP_REPLACE` too:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_REPLACE(val, '^([0-9]*)([^[:digit:]]*)([0-9]*)(.*)$', '\1.\3'))
  FROM table;
```

Voila...

Answer (score 0):

How about using `translate` to strip out the unwanted characters.

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(TRANSLATE('14dollars10cents','1234567890dolarscents','1234567890')) FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score -2):

No I don't think there is direct way.
you can do string parsing to get your integer value.

Comment: Can you show an example of how u do string parsing to get any integer value? Thanks

Comment: Check: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0303stolze/0303stolze1.html

Comment: there is an issue that i can't create function due to administrator rights. Is there any other ways ?